# What are these words written on a Kotel stone?

Tags: kotel-western-wall

I was at the Kotel earlier this year, and my eye was drawn to this particular stone because of the dove roosting there. I happened to notice there seemed to be some words written/carved into it, but it wasn't clear enough for me to make it out. It seems like the last word of the top line is יעקב but I'm not fully sure.

[This answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/97481/writing-on-the-stones-of-the-western-wall) suggests that there used to be a practice of writing your name directly on the wall. However, as can be seen in the second photo, this was relatively high up on the wall.

I have higher res photos, but they were too large to put here.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I've never seen this before.  Can you crop the hi-res photo to that stone and upload?

Comment: I have a pdf that will help you understand the practice -- how can I get it to you? @eliezer

Comment: There's a verse from Isaiah 66 a few stones over https://israelcitytour.blogspot.com/2010/07/blog-post_96.html

Comment: @Eliezer https://kotar.cet.ac.il/kotarapp/index/Chapter.aspx?nBookID=99352300&nTocEntryID=99353587

Comment: @Deuteronomy the pdf is at the link I posted (I think). If you can't get it there, we can work on getting the copy I have to you.

Comment: @Deuteronomy I sent the pages I had which deal with this (it isn't the entire of the book, but relevant pages)

Comment: @rosends Thanks, much appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I t is difficult to make out, but appears to be a phrase saying:
ידיד יי יוסף יעקב
That would translate as:
Dear friend of G-d, Yosef Yaacov.
There are a few letters before ידיד, and part of a second line of text below it.

Looking closely at the surrounding stones that are dressed the same way, there appear to be traces of similar writing.

The writing does not look like it was engraved into the stone, but was some kind of surface treatment on top of the stone, perhaps something with some kind of acid wash.

Investigating this technique a little further suggests that perhaps the writing is a kind of limestone concrete paste that could have been applied to the finished stone surface afterward to achieve intricate writing.

Here’s a link discussing the use of such paste with stone.

https://rootsofprogress.org/instant-stone-just-add-water

Answer (score 4):

The ground level was higher in the 19th century and when the kotel plaza was built, the whole area was excavated to a lower level. The roman street level is even lower in the enclosed area to the left of the plaza they have glass floors to see lower.